# Nginx rewrite doesn't work when I try to match a file

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I need to convert in Nginx these .htaccess rules, but when I try to target the filename and its extensions, Nginx doesn't match it. I really don't understand why of this behavior.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(test_mod_rewrite) /$1media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/modrewrite.php?q=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(gz|nz)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(js|css)$  /$1media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/jscss.php?f=$5&type=$6&gz=$2&d=$3&i=$4
```

I converted these rules in Nginx:

```
location /media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/ {
    rewrite ^/(test_mod_rewrite) /media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/modrewrite.php?q=$1;
    rewrite ^/(gz|nz)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(js|css)$ /$1media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/jscss.php?f=$4&type=$5&gz=$1&d=$2&i=$3;
}
```

The example URL is:

`/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/gz/30/0/d8604b25d503f1dcbb035ec731857648.css`

What I'm wrong?

Comment: Why is there a space before the closing tag (`$`) here? `rewrite ^/(gz|nz)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.(js|css) $` ... Have you tried using [this tool](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) to convert your rules?

Comment: My mistake copying the code in the editor, edited. Yes, initially I've used that tool but don't work